# Difference between Objective-C and Swift user desired function?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

I am trying to dump the class and method names used in the iOS application. I found that in Objective-C if I call the user defined function on button click. I am able to see both user defined functions and other functions used in the class; whereas, in Swift I am only able to dump the class and button method name not user defined function.

Can anyone tell me what could be the reason of this? Is there any difference in the implementation of functions is Objective-C and Swift?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any difference in the implementation of functions is objc and swift?

Yes, everything in Swift not explicitly exposed to Objective-C is invisible to Objective-C. The Swift button action handler is marked as an `@IBAction`, which exposes it to Objective-C. But the other function has no `@objc` marking, so it is invisible.

Comment: But in Swift button is also marked as an IBAction but in swift I am not able to see user defined function but in ObjC i can see.